# Display select values of a radio button from a radio group

Tags: android

I have a radio button group that has four radio buttons. I am trying to create a scenario were when a user clicks on a radio button the value of that radio button would be display to him. But my code is not working.

This is my radio button group calling the onclick listener

```
buttongroup.setOnClickListener(buttongroupListener);
```

The line above is placed in the onCreate View.

```
private OnClickListener buttongroupListener = new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String selectedValue = "";
    // Is the button now checked?

  if(view.getId() == R.id.buttoncontainer){
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    int selectedRadioID = buttongroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    if(checked){

        switch(selectedRadioID){

            case R.id.radioButton1:
                selectedValue = "A";
                break;
            case R.id.radioButton2:
                selectedValue = "B";
                break;
            case R.id.radioButton3:
                selectedValue = "C";
                break;
            case R.id.radioButton4:
                selectedValue = "D";
                break;
        }
    }
 }



    Toast.makeText(context, selectedValue,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better option I can suggest is to use `RadioGroup` event as below :

```
 RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
       switch(checkedId){

        case R.id.radioButton1:
            selectedValue = "A";
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton2:
            selectedValue = "B";
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton3:
            selectedValue = "C";
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton4:
            selectedValue = "D";
            break;
    }
    }Toast.makeText(context, selectedValue,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

});
```

Comment: Thanks I am trying it. bro